# Gulp with Bourbon/Neat, no mixin named media

Tags: css, sass, gulp, bourbon, neat

I'm taking over a project and I can't get gulp to compile the CSS, I get the error:

```
Error: assets/sass/pages/_global.sass
Error: no mixin named media

       Backtrace:
        assets/sass/pages/_global.sass:86
        on line 86 of assets/sass/pages/_global.sass
     @include media($md) {
```

But everything appears to be included properly and the mixin is there/included before this section.  I've used SASS before but no gulp or bourbon, so I'm a bit stumped on this one.

Here's the CSS from that section:

```
body
  +padding(45px 0 0 0)
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif
  overflow-x: hidden
  +margin(40px 0 0 0)
  color: $ft_dark_brown
  +media($md)
    +padding(113px 0 0 0)
```

Comment: Are you sure Neat is being imported correctly in addition to Bourbon? They are totally separate, though unidirectionally dependent. Without seeing the file structure and how files are being imported it's hard to answer this.

Comment: Neat is already there/imported before the custom CSS.  I moved this project to another computer and it worked, the source code was the exact same, no idea why it choked on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install "neat" using the npm package manager, it is set to version 1.9.1 -  both the default version and `@latest`.  So you may have been trying to access a mixin that had a different name in that version.

If anyone is getting a similar error after installing via npm, use the specific version you wish to use, e.g. `npm install bourbon-neat^2.0.0`

**Edit:**

It is not set to 1.9.1, but rather the most recently update by date.  And as bourbon/neat maintain multiple releases (I think 2.x.x and 3.x.x now), the default version may not be the actual newest version.  I believe there was a recent fix that now allows `npm install bourbon-neat@latest` to point to the highest version number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the grid system Neat also.. http://neat.bourbon.io/